# Get only the calendars that the user has write permissions for

Tags: office365, office365api

We have an integration that syncs our calendar with a user's 365 calendar. The problem is that the current endpoints [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/calendar-rest-operations#Getcalendars) return calendars that are read-only (eg. calendar added via ical)

We need to ensure that the calendar IDs we receive are writable. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: You can get read/write access to the signed in user's calendar by requesting Calendar.ReadWrite access when getting an OAuth token.  Are you not able to do this?

Comment: I have the ReadWrite access - the problem is that the user has mutliple calendars under "My Calendars" - some of which are read-only. One such calendar was added via the 'add from internet' option and specifying an ical address

Answer (score 0):

You can get this from the `https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/calendars` [endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/calendar-rest-operations#GetCalendars). This will return a collection of Calendar objects:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/$metadata#Me/Calendars",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.id": "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users('ddfcd489-628b-40d7-b48b-57002df800e5@1717622f-1d94-4d0c-9d74-709fad664b77')/Calendars('AAMkAGI2TGuLAAA=')",
            "Id": "AAMkAGI2TGuLAAA=",
            "Name": "Calendar",
            "Color": "Auto",
            "ChangeKey": "nfZyf7VcrEKLNoU37KWlkQAAA0x0+w==",
            "CanShare":true,
            "CanViewPrivateItems":true,
            "CanEdit":true,
            "Owner":{
              "Name":"Fanny Downs",
              "Address":"fannyd@adatum.onmicrosoft.com"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```